# Quantum Teleportation - how to prove the general case?

Tags: linear-algebra, information-theory, quantum-computation

I've taken a course of quantum information theory and although I can compute a quantum teleportation in an explicit case where I'm given a quantum entanglement shared by Alice and Bob (normally 1/root(2) (|00> + |11>) ) I'm a bit stuck on this general example.

Specifically, I can't seem to "Show that Bob then has the state...".

[image: Here is the problem]

Any help or advice on how to approach/prove this would be great - my university doesn't provide any solutions for past papers unfortunately.

Comment: This is extremely poorly written: in the beginning, the vectors $\eta _k$ form a basis in $\mathcal H _2$; later on we discover that the same vectors live in $\mathcal H _1$, being the first factors in the tensor product giving $\epsilon$. This is the kind of notation that makes me stop reading a text. The author of the above problem should be fined.